# Alternate option of Amazon Kinesis Video Streams

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, xaml, .net-framework-version

Please suggest some material or links so that I can create a small project .net on Live streaming Like Amazon Kinesis Video Streams.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't yet have support for .NET.

One way is to take the C or C++ producer SDK project, compile it for Windows (which it supports), create a library with most of the logic for the .NET or use the APIs directly and write a thin .NET wrapper/interop code on top of it that exposes the functionality to .NET.